# Why is there a long delay when using `nohup` on Linode

Tags: ssh, shell, nohup

I have a shell script like:

```
for((i=1;i<500;i++))
do
  python get_sequence.py
done
```

I want to run it on a Linode VPS. It would take a few days to run, so I'm going to use `nohup ./run.sh &`, so that I don't have to keep the ssh connection for days.

The question is that when I use `nohup`, there is always a long delay (tens of minutes) before each of the python process runs. I feel that there seems to be a queue, and the processes by `nohup` could not be run immediately.

I have tried to run the script directly without `nohup`, and it was very fast without delay.

I wonder why there's a delay when `nohup`? How to avoid it?